# enable/disable an input form field based on a checkbox value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing an Angular app where i use check boxes in a formgroup. I have second form group with multuiple text inputs. I want to enable the selected text input in the second form when particular check box in other form is enabled.

FormGroup1

```
 <div class="list"> 
    <form [formGroup] = "f1FormGroup" (ngSubmit)="f1(f1FormGroup.value)" #form1 = "ngForm" >
        <h2>i1</h2>
        <h5> <input type="checkbox" name="i1" value="i1" [(ngModel)]="i1.isChecked" > i1 </h5>
        <h5><input type="checkbox" name="i2" value="i2" [(ngModel)]="i2.isChecked" > i2  </h5>
    </form>
</div>
```

FormGroup2

```
<div id="i1m" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
        <div  class="col-sm-5">
            <span class="close" (click) = "close1()">&times;</span>
            <h2>RV</h2>  
            <form class="st" [formGroup] = "i1mFormGroup">  
                <h6>Material</h6>
                <input type="text" id="m1" placeholder="Optional" name="m1" value="m1">
                <h6>TC</h6>
            <select matNativeControl required>
                <option value="1">C</option>
                <option value="2">H</option>
                <option value="2">S</option>
            </select>
            <h6>SH</h6>
            <input type="text" id="m2" placeholder="1" disabled>
            <button mat-button type="submit" (click) = "save1()">Save</button> 
        </form>     
    </div> 
</div>
```

component.ts

```
t1(i1){
    if(this.i1.isChecked){
        document.getElementById("i1m").style.display = "block";
    } else{

        document.getElementById("i1m").style.display = "none";
    }
}

close1(){
    document.getElementById("i1m").style.display = "none";
}

save1(){
    document.getElementById("i1m").style.display = "none";
}
```

I want to enable the textbox in formgroup2 with id m2 only when the check box i2 in formgroup1 is checked and display formgroup2 with m2 textbox.if i1 is checked the formgroup2 should be displayed without m2 textbox. please guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
 my i1FormGroup(FormGroup2) is a a pop up modal which pop up for each checkbox checked in f1FormGroup(FormGroup1) individually. Based on the checkbox checked the inputs are enabled or disabled. The other input values remain same when entered once.

I added a StackBlitz and explained briefly in the comments in the App.components.ts page at the bottom. Please check it. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpogjm)

Comment: ...you should use a different approach. Means... don't use the DOM API! Use bindings! You also can access formControls through the form API...

Comment: Hi Okyo, Thanks for your time. can you please elaborate or provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: If you add a stackblitz we could make some changed there directly

Comment: Hi @MoxxiManagarm i added StackBlitz can you please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. Don't use `ngModel` with reactive forms. Secondly, **don't** manipulate the DOM. Angular usually have own tools for doing what you want. In this case, I've gone all reactive, and based on the checkbox status, you can call `disable()` or `enable()` on the formcontrols. Here is a sample:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  // form with checkboxes
  this.f1FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    cb1: [false],
    cb2: [false]
  })

  // form with inputs
  this.i1mFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    inp1: [''],
    inp2: ['']
  })

  // listen to the changes of the checkboxes and disable/enable when wanted
  this.f1FormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    value.cb1 ? this.i1mFormGroup.get('inp1').disable() : this.i1mFormGroup.get('inp1').enable()
  })
}
```

Also then add `formControlName` to the template, and remove `ngModel`.

Here's a demo: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npzjnh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi AJT_82, Thanks for your time. It works perfect but my i1FormGroup is a a pop up modal which pop up for each checkbox checked in f1FormGroup individually. Based on the checkbox checked the inputs are enabled or disabled.

Comment: Please could you create a stackblitz for this and I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Hi, I have created a stackblitz with your example. can you please have a look at it. I have explained the problem clearly in the bottom of app.component.ts.  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpogjm)

Comment: okay, I'll take a look. So do you want to actually hide or disable the fields based on your conditions? I suddenly became a bit confused on how you want it done :)

Comment: I want to hide them. i tried it but unable to work around it. that's why i wanted to disable it. If Hiding is possible. It will be Great.

Comment: @ramkris, check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9ws4z?file=src/app/app.component.html